# PHP loop multi array to get value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, foreach

i have:

```
$tag = ['a','b','c'];
$array = [0:{a:'name',b:'age',c:'address',d:'a',e:'job'},
1:{a:'name2',b:'age2',c:'address2',d:'b',e:'job2'},
2:{a:'name3',b:'age3',c:'address3',d:'b',e:'job3'},
3:{a:'name4',b:'age4',c:'address4',d:'c',e:'job4'},
3:{a:'name5',b:'age5',c:'address5',d:'a',e:'job5'}];
```

how i can loop to push to new array? result:

```
$array1 = [0:{a:'name',b:'age',c:'address',d:'a',e:'job'},
1:{a:'name5',b:'age5',c:'address5',d:'a',e:'job5'}];
$array2 = [0:{a:'name2',b:'age2',c:'address2',d:'b',e:'job2'},
1:{a:'name3',b:'age3',c:'address3',d:'b',e:'job3'}];
$array3 = [{a:'name4',b:'age4',c:'address4',d:'c',e:'job4'}];
```

Comment: What's the algorithm you want to use to create those new arrays? It's not obvious why you want name and name5 in the first array, name2 and name3 in the second, etc. Also, do you really need to create dynamically named variables (array1, array2, etc.)? That's certainly possible, but real use cases are quite rare.

Comment: Because i want sort by key "d" as $Tag Array :(